# ssrs report with sharepoint dataset in ie

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report with two datsets 1 of sharepoint and another of  sql.When I am previewing the report in SSRS,I am able to view the report,

but after deploying the report, when I am trying to access in IE,I am getting the following error.

"The report server cannot process the report or shared dataset. The shared data source 'DataSource1' for the report server or SharePoint site is not valid. Browse to the server or site and select a shared data source. "

```
                      Please help
```

Comment: Do you use SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio for report deployment?

Comment: Did you deploy all shared datasets and datasources? You can try to open reports library, open report context menu and select 'Manage Shared Data Sets' or 'Manage Data Sources'

Comment: @Greg,I have deployed everything and I could see the shared datasources in the datasources section.I have no shared datasets for this report.Also I created a copy of this report with embedded datasources,but still of no use.

Comment: What is in the sharepoint logs?

Comment: @Greg,There is some DNS involved between sharepoint and RS which is preventing the access.I think the issue will now be solved. Thank you